# Is there any npm package to make odbc connection from node js?

Tags: node.js, odbc

I am currently using windows machine and looking to connect the pervasive database using ODBC connection.

I tried to install the odbc npm (npm install odbc) but that is always failing due to errors.

Please provide me some details if there is any other plugin available to do the same.

Thanks
Vipin Mittal

Comment: I also need this question answered. Also like to know if there is a way to connect via JDBC.